# Key->Value or Value when returning (multiple) parts of an Association

Tags: associations, list-manipulation

There seems to be an idiom whereby multiple parts generates Key->Value forms whereas for single part specifications, only a Value is returned. This however, can lead to inconsistencies as follows:

```
      assoc = <|"a" -> 7, b -> 8, "c" -> 9|>;
      {Query[{1, 2}][assoc], Query[1][assoc], Query[2][assoc]}
 (* -> {<|"a" -> 7, b -> 8|>, 7, 8} *)
```

but doesn't this contradict the documentation on multiple queries?

```
 Query::Docs] {op_1, op_2, ...} apply multiple operators at once to the result, yielding a list
```

firstly, a list is not "yielded" (returned) and secondly, each application of the operator ordinarily returns a value. A more consistent usage would therefore appear to be?

```
Query[{1, 2}][assoc]
(* -> {7, 8}  *)

(* not valid existing input/output - suggestive only *)
```

In addition, the mere presence of a range (e.g. `1 ;; 2`) seems to induce individually specified parts to now return Values?

```
Query[{1, 2, 1 ;; 2}][assoc]
(*->  {7, 8, <|"a" -> 7, b -> 8|>} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

In an earlier comment RunnyKine gave an example involving `Key["a"]` which if followed though provides an explanation. It also means that there is a subtle change in semantics using `Part` with an `Association`. Consider

```
 Query[{Key["a"], 2}]@assoc
 (* -> Missing["PartInvalid", {Key["a"], 2}] *)
```

suggesting that a list is *not* being interpreted as containing multiple queries but rather, it is being considered as a *single* query. Hence,

```
  Query[{1, 2}]@assoc
  (* ->  <|"a" -> 7, b -> 8|> *)
```

is *not* being parsed as a list of two queries (as the following unambiguously is)

```
Query[{Query@1, 2}]@assoc
(* -> {7, 8} *)
```

but instead is being parsed as

```
Query[Query[{1, 2}]]@assoc
(* -> <|"a" -> 7, b -> 8|> *)
```

or

```
assoc[[{1, 2}]]
(* -> <|"a" -> 7, b -> 8|> *)
```

but this in itself indicates a subtle semantic shift in the interpretation of `Part` between a `List` and an `Association`. The analogous

```
ls = {7, 8, 9};
ls[[{1, 2}]] 
(* ->  {7, 8} *)
```

has semantics - "take the list's first part -ls[[1]]- and its second part -ls[[2]]- and wrap them in a list - in other words it is the standard notational implementation of *listability* used throughout the Wolfram Language.

This interpretation no longer applies with an Association since `assoc[[{1}]] (* -> <| a-> 7 |> *)` now essentially says "wrapping parts in a list is not implementing listability for an `Association` but instead is simply a signal to include keys with specified parts". Personally I think it would have been more coherent to maintain a consistency with listability (especially since `KeyTake` can be used to return Key/Value pairs) as such consistency usually avoids the need for any disambiguation such as in this example.