# about the design of Part related to Association

Tags: associations

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1]]
```

gives values

```
1
```

while

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1;;2]]
```

gives

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
```

**I just feel an inconsistency in this kind of `Part` design.**

Why

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1]]
```

doesn't give

```
"a" -> 1
```

as

```
{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4}[[1]]
```

gives

```
"a" -> 1
```

or as many people point out that functions act transparently on `Association`'s values, why doesn't

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1;;2]]
```

give

```
{1,2}
```

??? Can somebody give an explanation?

Comment: I agree. It is not consistent. May be it is a bug?

Comment: I think I figured it. To obtain the whole part, i.e. `(key->value)`, one must use `[[n;;n]]` syntax or `[[n;;]]`. But if you use `[[n]]` this will only give the value at part `n`. The reason why `[[n;;m]]` work for both `key,values` at both `n` through `m` parts, is because of the `;;` usage. So to pull both key+value, use `;;`, else it will default to only the value at that part.

Comment: @Nasser Yeah, it is definitely not a bug. They designed it in this way! They write these example in the help doc. But it just doesn't consistent with Part of List.

Comment: @Nasser `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>[[{1, 2}]]` also behaves as `Span` does. My guess is that the creator assumed that someone who uses `Span` is collecting several elements. i.e. the intention is to make this change when the user requests more than one element.

Comment: @Nasser I think this inconsistency is awkward. It declares that there is a special case in using `Part` in `Association`, not elegant. What do you think?

Comment: I found more documentation on part with association. it is all here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html about half way down the page. many examples.

Comment: This behavior has been noted before: [(56013)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56013/key-value-or-value-when-returning-multiple-parts-of-an-association?rq=1)

Comment: I guess it is consistent. check <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[;;1]] and <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[;;2]]. and also <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1]] and <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[2]]

Comment: Yes, I think as well it is consistent. Observe that  for an expression f[x,y,z,u,v,w], the Part function returns an argument only when it is called with a single number, in all other cases, such as 1;;2, {3,2,1}, the result has head f.
With Associations, it is almost the same. Part with a number gives the value, in all other cases it gives an Association

Comment: With your last question you are misunderstanding the effect of `Span`. It returns the selected parts wrapped in their *original* head. So you only get a `List` back if you are extracting parts from a `List`. For example `f[1, 2, 3][[1;;2]]` gives `f[1, 2]` **not** `{1, 2}`.

Comment: @SimonWoods Well, My last question is actually a question about the transparency of `Association`. Since assoc[[1]] directly acts on values of assoc, then why doesn't assoc[[span]] gives collection of values? I admit I made a mistake. Like you said, original head should be preserved. Then, `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1;;2]]` should give `<|1,2|>`, but this is not an association!It is a contradiction! So they must make it as `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>`. Wow, maybe this is what the creators of `Association` thought in their mind!!! You enlightened me!:) What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

IMO the behavior is consistent, and acts like in Lists.

For Lists we have:

```
{"a", "b", "c", "d"}[[1]]
{"a", "b", "c", "d"}[[{1}]]
```

> ```
> "a"
> {"a"}
> ```

and for Associations:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1]]
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[{1}]]
```

> ```
> 1
> <|"a" -> 1|>
> ```

For for the `Spam` form `;;` the result is always like a list inside `Part`, so:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[{1}]]
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1;;1]]
```

are equivalent.

Comment: I agree, the behaviour of Part with Association is consistent and expected.

Comment: @SimonWoods But why `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>[[1]]` doesn't give `"a" -> 1`?

Comment: @matheorem, because the **value** is not the rule `"a"->1`, it is just `1`. Note that `FreeQ[<|"a"->1|>, Rule]` is `True` - there is no `Rule` in that expression, despite appearances.

Comment: @SimonWoods But the `FullForm[<|"a"->1|>]` gives `Association[Rule["a",1]]`. There is `Rule`.

Comment: @matheorem, there's some discussion of that [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55526/matchq-ing-associations-mma-10). I don't claim to fully understand the situation, but I have found that associations mostly make sense if you regard the values as being what's *really there* at level 1, and the keys as ephemeral magic labels which are transparent to most operations and which vanish as soon as the value is no longer contained inside an association.

Comment: @SimonWoods It still confused me now, and according to Taliesin Beynon's comment, if seems that `Association` is not mature at present stage, am I right?

Comment: @matheorem, it looks like there is still some work to do with pattern matching on Associations, but I wouldn't expect the behaviour with `Part` to change.